How to configure CosmosDB to trigger a typeScript Azure Function using Managed Identity?
I successfully configured my TypeScript Azure Function 'functionInsertDataInCosmosDb' to write messages to CosmosDB using Managed Identity in my local development environment.
Here is my local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGE": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT": "https://test-dev-store-emails.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "COSMOS_DB_DATABASE": "cosmosdb--test-database",
    "cosmosdb__accountEndpoint": "https://test-dev-store-emails.documents.azure.com:443/"
  }
}

Now, I'm configuring another TypeScript Azure Function named 'receiveMessageFromCosmosDb' to process messages using CosmosDB trigger with Managed Identity. Here's my 'receiveMessageFromCosmosDb' function code:
import { app, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
export async function reciveMessageFromCosmosDb(
  documents: unknown[],
  context: InvocationContext
): Promise<void> {
  context.log(`Cosmos DB function processed ${documents} documents`);

}

app.cosmosDB('reciveMessageFromCosmosDb', {
  connection: 'cosmosdb__accountEndpoint',
  databaseName: 'COSMOS_DB_DATABASE',
  containerName: 'emails',
  createLeaseContainerIfNotExists: true,
  handler: reciveMessageFromCosmosDb
});


I've already assigned the required RBAC permission 'Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor' to my Function App. However, when I debug my functions, the following error appears in 'receiveMessageFromCosmosDb':
The 'reciveMessageFromCosmosDb' function is in error:
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 
'Functions.reciveMessageFromCosmosDb'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create container 
information for emails in database COSMOS_DB_DATABASE with lease leases in
 database COSMOS_DB_DATABASE : Cosmos DB connection configuration 
'cosmosdb__accountEndpoint' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cosmos DB 
connection configuration 'cosmosdb__accountEndpoint' does not exist. Make 
sure that it is a defined App Setting.

Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Please read [ask] and then edit your question to show your work (provide a [mcve]). Right now, you only posted a requirement.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74185934/azure-function-cosmosdb-trigger-managed-identity-not-working

I've already read this question 10 times, and it's didn't work.

Please see Azure Function cosmosDB trigger managed identity not working as explained in the comments. It is the same scenario.
Your code is defining:
 connection: 'cosmosdb__accountEndpoint',

This is wrong, the value of connection should be the value of the prefix that contains both the accountEndpoint and the credential.
It should be:
 connection: 'cosmosdb',

And your settings file:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGE": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "COSMOS_DB_DATABASE": "cosmosdb--test-database",
    "cosmosdb": {
      "accountEndpoint": "https://test-dev-store-emails.documents.azure.com:443/",
      <here you need to add the MSI properties>
    }
  }
}

Which MSI properties to use when running locally is up to you, but you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=cosmos&pivots=programming-language-csharp#local-development-with-identity-based-connections
And when this is deployed to Azure, the Application Settings would use the __ syntax:
"cosmosdb__accountEndpoint": "https://test-dev-store-emails.documents.azure.com:443/"

"cosmosdb__credential": "managedidentity"

As a side note, the code is also incorrectly using COSMOS_DB_DATABASE. If you want values to be replaced by configuration values, you need to use the Bindings Expression:
databaseName: '%COSMOS_DB_DATABASE%',


I followed the steps you provided, but I'm still encountering an error:
"The 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' setting is required. Please specify a valid value. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2257963 for more information. The application will continue to run, but may throw an exception in a future release."
It's strange because the FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME setting is defined in my local.settings.json file.
Thank you so much for your assistance

Please make sure the content of the settings file is correct json. There might be something (a missing character) that is rendering it as invalid.

This error is appering too:
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
I've validate my local.settings.json file.

I found the solution following Matias Quaranta's explanation.
Here is my working local.settings.json configuration:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AZUREWEBJOBSSTORAGE": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "COSMOS_DB_DATABASE": "cosmosdb--test-database",
    "COSMOSDB_CONNECTION__accountEndpoint": "https://test-dev-store-emails.documents.azure.com:443/"
  }
}

And my receiveMessageFromCosmosDb' function code:
import { app, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
export async function receiveMessageFromCosmosDb(
  documents: unknown[],
  context: InvocationContext
): Promise<void> {
  context.log(`Cosmos DB function processed ${documents} documents`);

}

app.cosmosDB('receiveMessageFromCosmosDb', {
  connection: 'COSMOSDB_CONNECTION',
  databaseName: process.env.COSMOS_DB_DATABASE,
  containerName: 'emails',
  createLeaseContainerIfNotExists: true,
  handler: receiveMessageFromCosmosDb
});

This solution works both in my local development environment and when deployed to Azure Functions.
